# Angular: CORS error even though headers are set

Tags: angular, request, cors, http-headers

I keep getting a CORS issue and I'm not sure why. The error says that the GET request I'm trying to make has failed, but there isn't much of an explanation about why it failed.
This is how I'm setting the headers in my frontend Angular code:
[image]

This image shows the headers are being set correctly (since they show up in the request):
[image]

This is the error I'm seeing in the console:
[image]

And then this is the request in the networks tab (focusing on the first request made to `/servers`):
[image]
[image]

When I try to access the /servers endpoint in postman or my browser, it returns the necessary information, which just confirms that the error is occurring when connecting the frontend of my code to the backend.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks!

EDIT: I've looked at many of the other similar questions posted online and a lot of them go over making sure the correct headers are included. Since the error I'm having doesn't have much of a description, I'm not sure what to look at. I've already included a screenshot demonstrating that the headers are being set. Solutions to another similar question encouraged the user to look into how their backend was connected to their front-end, but since the browser says that this is a CORS issue, I think the issue must be occurring on the front-end. Just in case I looked over the backend code, and it looks like the ports are set correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually first I think the problem is that you set headers in frontend code. You have to set them in backend. You can see for tips here: https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/

If backend is third party and you do not have access, then you need proxy https://medium.com/tribalscale/stop-cursing-cors-c2cbb4997057 (have't tried with proxies).

> but since the browser says that this is a CORS issue, I think the issue must be occurring on the front-end.

The browser just says because it is trying to protect users.